# Maven resource filter not working

Tags: java, maven, resources, filtering

I'm trying to make use of Maven's (v3) resource filtering capabilities to replace some variables in my `application.properties` file, with a property in my `pom.xml`.
The properties file resides in `src/main/resources` and contains:

```
application.version=${project.version}
```

My pom file contains:

```
<project ...>
...
<version>1.0.0</version>
...
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>              
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  ...
</build>
```

When I run goal (via eclipse run config) `clean process-resources package` and take a look at the properties file in `target/classes`, nothing has changed... the value remains the same.

Comment: everything seems fine, it should be replaced even when running from within Eclipse. Did you try to run it from command line, as a double check? moreover, you don't need to run `process-resources` then `package`, running `package` it will already run `process-resources` and any preceeding phase.

Comment: Yes, tried that as well... no luck.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with my build plugin: `spring-boot-maven-plugin`

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution. Since I am using the `spring-boot-starter-parent`, there is a different required syntax for the property variables. Instead of `${...}`, you must used `@...@`. Here is the reference that I used: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.3-Release-Notes#maven-resources-filtering